# Configure frontend to use B2C for authentication (in NuxtJS)

Tags: azure-active-directory, nuxt.js, azure-ad-b2c, nuxt-auth

I'm stack in my very first task of my very first job as Front-End developer, I know I am hindered, but I hope you will be able to help me.

My task is the same as in the title, to configure the frontend to use b2c for authentication, I don't have to impletement the authentication itself, just to configure the b2c, I will explain a little bit the project so that you can understand better:

They have a main App which is already working perfectly and it is stable, what they want to do is to build a platform aside, where the the customers can send their complains, on this platform every customer should login automatically with the credentials of the main App.

They provided me the entrypontins (for authorization, the token endpoint and the end session endpoint), the jwks uri and the cliendID, the App is build in Nuxtjs and they are using Azure AD B2C as directory service. The App is absolutely empty, it was just created and the configuration I have to do is the very first thing that should be implemented.

I have found a lot of theory informations on the web, but I cannot manage to find a guide that could help me to implement it practically, and the most of the practic tutorials/docs are about implementing the full process of authentication.

I am wondering if some of you knows a nice tutorial or guide or something that could help me to take a few steps forward.

I thank you all in advance !!

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? SO is not a coding service.

Comment: Implementing the config. on it's own is pointless. You can't test it.

Comment: Any of the flows here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/integrate-with-app-code-samples - will give you guidance since the config is the same.